# dc.js pie chart not all labels are shown

Tags: dc.js

[image: Pie missing labels]

I have set these properties in pie chart, still labels are not fully visible.labels are only visible on clicking on any of the slice, but it is not visible when the page it loaded,what should i do now?

```
    yearChart
    .width(200)
    .height(200)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(countPerYear)
    .innerRadius(20)            
    .drawPaths(true)
    .externalRadiusPadding(30)
    .externalLabels(40);          


    monthChart
    .width(200)
    .height(200)
    .dimension(dist)
    .group(countPerDist)
    .innerRadius(20)
    .drawPaths(true)
    .externalRadiusPadding(30)
    .externalLabels(40);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. I only had to add `.minAngleForLabel(0)` so that all labels are shown.

[image: Pie labels showing]

```
yearChart
            .width(300)
            .height(300)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .group(countPerYear)                        
            .drawPaths(true)
            .externalRadiusPadding(60)
            .minAngleForLabel(0)
            .externalLabels(40);
```

Comment: Thanks for following up! I wonder if `minAngleForLabel` should be disabled when `externalLabels` are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust **width,height** with **externalRadiusPadding**

**try this**

```
yearChart
.width(300)
.height(300)
.dimension(yearDim)
.group(countPerYear)
.innerRadius(20)            
.drawPaths(true)
.externalRadiusPadding(90)
.externalLabels(40);          


monthChart
.width(300)
.height(300)
.dimension(dist)
.group(countPerDist)
.innerRadius(20)
.drawPaths(true)
.externalRadiusPadding(90)
.externalLabels(40);
```

Comment: Already tried adjust width,height with external Radius Padding but still labels are not visible,while adjusting width height and external radius only pie chart has change but it does not show any effect on labels.